# Config mysql in Docker

Tags: mysql, docker

I am really newbie to Docker. I want to deploy my app with docker and use docker-compose to manage my database (make connection, make initial schema). But I really confuse how to achieve that. Here's my config code:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: currency
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ''
    ports:
      - "33061:3306"
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

And when I run `docker-compose up` it refused to connect db:

```
errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
web_1  |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
web_1  |   syscall: 'connect',
web_1  |   address: '127.0.0.1',
web_1  |   port: 3306,
web_1  |   fatal: true
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Hi! Could you check that you have nothing running on `:3306` ? (`lsof -i :3306` if on linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[docker networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/#scope-of-this-topic)**, then put your containers into that network. So they can talk to each other. In your containers you can call each container by its DNS name, from your web container you can refer mysql host as just `db`. Please have a look below docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: currency
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: ''
    ports:
    - "33061:3306"
    networks:
    - appnet
    volumes:
    -./my_mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
    - .:/code
    ports:
    - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
    - db
    networks:
    - appnet
networks:
  appnet:
    driver: "bridge"
```

- You can connect to the mysql container with your **host** mysql
  client(Mysql Workbench, SequelPro ..etc) with `host: localhost;
  port:33061`. Then you can create you schemas there!
- If you want to persist the data of you mysql container,
  you can add a volume, make sure to create the *my_mysql_data* folder

Comment: Thanks. But how to create schema inside docker container? Is it possible to deploy app inside docker container but use mysql server outside the docker (i.e using XAMPP)?

Comment: I added some more info to the answer.